# PhantomJS performance

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs

My question is, what is the most efficient configuration for PhantomJS tests.

Currently I have 1 instance of PhantomJS running and every instance can have 2 tabs opened (dev env).

Is it better to have more instance of phantomjs or opened tabs, and if tabs, what is the upper limit of PhantomJS.

CPU:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 2494.316
cache size  : 3072 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4988.63
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Memory:

```
           total      used       free             shared  buffers     cached
Mem:       2515896    1155828    1360068          0       171648      622668
```

More information:

I would like to handle multiple tests at once with as less memory as possible. Now I am running two pages per phantom instance, and already I am having issues with network requests. I have a timeout of 20s and if a specific network request is not finished in that time, test fails.

Test is successful if I only run one page in one PhantomJS instance, but that is not optimal, because we will be running more then 1000 tests, and I would like to arrange tests in multiple pages across multiple phantomjs instances.

Example:

- 10 phantomjs instances
- every phantomjs instance can run 30 pages

Now why when running multiple pages in one instance, does the network request lag so much?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? It will probably differ by hardware for every one who tries to get a benchmark like that. If you have your answer, you can post it here.

Comment: I tried with 1x50 tabs, with this PC, it took 68% of CPU at on point, but the main issue is, that loading of pages is slow when so many tabs are opened. (6 is already a problem)

Comment: It looks like using tabs instead of phantomjs instances is a performance problem. Phantomjs uses a lot more CPU when using tabs.

Comment: @DudeSweet did you solve this problem ?

Comment: No I went with node webkit for my testing tool